# Parsing raw apache logs

Tags: php, apache, parsing, logging

I need some php code for parsing raw apache logs. 
In particular, I want the number of times mode=search and the term used for searching. Here is an example:

```
207.46.195.228 - - [30/Apr/2010:03:24:26 -0700] "GET /index.php?mode=search&term=AE1008787E0174 HTTP/1.1" 200 13047 "-" "msnbot/2.0b (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm)"
212.81.200.167 - - [30/Apr/2010:04:21:43 -0700] "GET /index.php?mode=search&term=WH2002D-YYH HTTP/1.1" 200 12079 "http://www.mysite.com/SearchGBY.php?page=81" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; GTB6.4; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; WinuE v6; InfoPath.2; WinuE v6)"
212.81.200.167 - - [30/Apr/2010:04:21:44 -0700] "GET /file_uploads/banners/banner.swf HTTP/1.1" 200 50487 "-" "contype"
66.249.68.168 - - [30/Apr/2010:04:21:45 -0700] "GET /index.php?mode=search&term=WH2002D-YYH HTTP/1.1" 200 12079 "-" "Mediapartners-Google"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently wrote a very crude parser for this:

```
$ignore = array('css', 'png', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'js', 'ico');

$f = fopen('access_log', "r");
if(!$f) die("Failed to open log for reading.");

while (!feof($f)) {

    $buff = fgets($f, 4096);

    $parts = explode(' ', $buff);

    if(in_array(end(explode('.', $parts[6])), $ignore)) continue;

    $domain = trim(end($parts));

    // http method
    $http_method = substr($parts[5], 1);
    if($http_method != 'GET' && $http_method != 'POST') continue;

    // parse out the date
    list($d, $m, $y) = explode('/', substr($parts[3], 1));
    $y = substr($y, 0, 4);
    $time = strtotime("{$d} {$m} {$y}");

    print "{$time} {$parts[0]} {$http_method} {$parts[6]} $domain\n";
}
```

$parts[6] should contain the part you're interested in (the resource that was accessed). This should get you on your way...

Answer (score 0):

As easy as using regular expressions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php

Comment: Sorry, Casidiablo, regexs are too confusing to me. I've been programming for 20 years and *STILL* don't know or like them.

Comment: LOL... me too. But they are useful.

Comment: Regular expressions turn out to be the wrong tool for parsing strings most of the time, because the grammars you want to parse are often not regular. Did you check the grammar of Apache logs first?

Comment: erikb85: Regular expressions as we think of them have been extended to the point that if we're able to sense a pattern in the string, we're able to invent the grammar for that string on the spot and create a regex to parse it.  Apache logs lack a consistent grammar between the fields, with some fields surrounded with quotes, some with brackets, and some with nothing. So we need something like this: 
preg_match('/^(\S+) \S+ \S+ \[(.*?)\] "(\S+).*?" \d+ \d+ "(.*?)" "(.*?)"/', $line, $m)
Regular expressions are never the wrong tool to parse a string. Its why every language supports them